# What does the dot product represent when vectors are of different units of measure?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two vectors. One vector that's magnitude is measured in feet and the other vectors magnitude is measured in time.

What would the dot product of these two vectors represent, if anything? Would converting to unit vectors help?

Is it as illogical as calculating area having length of square in feet and width of square in units of time and thus area is nothing?

Comment: Google the definition of work from a physics standpoint. In that case we take the dot product of a force with a distance.

Answer (score 2):

As long as each vector has all elements with the same unit,
the dot product has units that are
the product of the respective units.

In your case,
that would be
distance times time.

As to what that means,
that is up to you
and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My degree is in physics, so I would say convert time to feet by multiplying by the speed of light, then the dot product would be in square feet.

Comment: thanks for your response. Interesting! Could you give me an example please of what youre talking about or by using a vector that represents hour of time?

Comment: do you think perhaps we could talk via email or chat?

Comment: yes e-mail sweeny_mark@hotmail.com